# Как удалить аккаунты на которые не заходили более 2 лет

Tags: mysql

Как удалить аккаунты на которые не заходили более 2 лет?
DELETE FROM `accounts` WHERE `pGetonDate` < '01/01/2018 00:01'
Так пробовал, не получилось. pGetonDate это дата последнего входа

Comment: Приведите пример записи, которая не удалилась из таблицы `accounts`

Comment: https://sun1-16.userapi.com/wHVU_LKBuO_qz367vs4hrAz-g1SR9cTuVR-6AQ/Z1BmIJatH0U.jpg

Comment: MySQL понимает только один формат даты - `YYYY-MM-DD`. Так что `DD/MM/YYYY` для него не дата, а бред собачий, и приведение константы к дате ожидаемо оканчивается на NULL, что делает условие отбора гарантированно невыполняющимся. Потому ничего и не удаляется....

Comment: @Akina А оно воспринимает такую строку как дату?

Comment: @Miron У MySQL нестрогая типизация. И такого понятия как "литерал даты" у него тупо нет (есть "строковый литерал, который может быть корректно приведён к типу даты"). А при сравнении - если сравнивается поле и литерал, и поле имеет любой тип даты/времени, то литерал приводится к дате.

Comment: @Akina Да даже если так, то в правильной записи даже при сравнении строк все должно правильно сравниваться. Так что тут большой вопрос, а преобразовывает ли оно к дате. Подчеркну - я в этой теме(внутреннее устройство приведения типов в MySQL) полнейший дилетант.

Comment: @Miron *в правильной записи даже при сравнении строк все должно правильно сравниваться.* При сравнении строк в том формате, какой использовал автор? вот уж вряд ли... *Так что тут большой вопрос, а преобразовывает ли оно к дате* Вопроса тут нет от слова "совсем". Если поле `pGetonDate` имеет тип даты-времени, литерал преобразуется к дате -> ошибка ->NULL->WHERE NULL-> ничего не удаляется. Если поле имеет строковый тип с тем же форматом, что и литерал, то преобразований не будет (если поле не имеет какой-то странный charset/collation), и для ИМЕННО ЭТОГО литерала удаление выполнится корректно.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ликбез. Под правильной записью имел в виду корректную запись даты.

Comment: @Miron Если что - всё строго, и всё расписано тут: [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Хотя MySQL и слабо типизирован, лучше, как по-мне, хранить в типах, предназначенных для этого, чтобы нельзя было выстрелить себе в ногу. Используйте для ваших целей `TIMESTAMP(10)`. Подробнее [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html).

Comment: *Используйте для ваших целей TIMESTAMP(10). Подробнее здесь.* А у него точно версия 4? *Вы использовали varchar для хранения строк.* А эти сведения откуда?